# Javascript touch events not working using phonegap app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, web, viewport

I have a problem with touch events in a phonegap application..
I have a parent div with 100% of device width/height and another element inside it with over 1000px width/height.
I am using javascript to drag the element around the container.. everything works fine on desktops but when it comes to mobile doesnt seem to work at all.

This is the example markup

```
<div id="borderBox" style="position:relative;border:1px solid black;width:520px;height:250px;overflow:hidden;">
<img id="draggableElement" src="http://tech.pro/_sotc/sites/default/files/202/images/duck.jpg" style="width:1024px;height:1024px;top:-333px;left:-500px;position:absolute;cursor:move;"/>
```

Here is the original code before I've changed the mouse events to touch events

[This is the code I used](http://jsfiddle.net/WBv9r/1/light/)

I wasted like 5 hours trying to find a fix, but unfortunately I found nothing that helped me with this.. 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Original code before touch events does no good. We would need to see the code where you are using touch event handling in order to help.

Comment: The code I am using is exacly the same I sent fiddle with but it contains touch events instead of click events. http://jsfiddle.net/WBv9r/88/

Comment: `eventObj.clientX`/`clientY` isn't going to work. You need to look at the `touches` array on the incoming event and use the `clientX`/`clientY` properties on the items there (probably just the first), like `eventObj.touches[0].clientX`.